# Unhide one column at a time

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro that unhides, one at a time, a series of adjacent columns.  For example, column e:jf is hidden.  I want a macro that each time it is run, will unhide the next hidden column (so f, then g, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub UnhideACol()
Dim HiddenRange As Range, c As Range
Set HiddenRange = Range("E1:JF1") 'Define your range here
For Each c In HiddenRange
    If c.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: It's too bad they removed your comment... personally I thought asking for a pony was totally reasonable.

Comment: I removed it, but I'm glad it got a laugh :)